# Secure Spring FrameworkUser Management

Tags: appsec, java, authorization, user-management

I got asked this question:

*"Any decent reusable / plug-able Spring user management systems (registration,  change pwd, reset etc)?*

*How do you guys do authz in Spring, including managing those roles in ui?"*

My first thought was http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/ but I haven't used it in a while and am not sure if it is easy to implement and deploy.

Any good recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

I use Spring Security extensively, but it's intended to solve a different set of problems than the ones you cited: registration, change-password, reset.  You'll still need to handle all that yourself.  Spring Security is a very effective tool for handling authentication, authorization, and access-control.

Answer (score 1):

I use spring security and I don't find it too difficult to implement it into spring based application.